# why my jQuery is not working when i am uploading on the website

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

When I write the code on console, its working. When I upload on the website it is not working.

I want to do a stripe card details fields validation. When the details are filled and while filling the border color of the box should be green same as card details

Code that I tried:

```
if (jQuery('.input-text.wc-credit-card-form-card-expiry').val() == '') {
    jQuery('.input-text.wc-credit-card-form-card-expiry').css('border-color', 'red');
}
else {
    jQuery('.input-text.wc-credit-card-form-card-expiry').css('border-color', 'green');
}
```

Webpage URL:
https://www.preprod.swett.se/checkout-2/

If you check on the website. Card number field is working correct. I want the expiration date and cvv field date should also work same as card details

Could you please help me with this jQuery.

Comment: For one, you have pasted the script outside of `body`.

Comment: Couple things: 1/ `Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3` (looks like you have 3.4.1 installed?) & `jQuery(...).validate is not a function`. It's going to be hard to debug any JS when you have all those JS errors in your console

Comment: Also: You're loading 2 different versions of jQuery, it's not recommended

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works, please make sure to include `jQuery`:

```
jQuery('#stripe-card-expiry').on('keyup', function(){
  var $input = jQuery(this);
  $input.css('border-color', !$input.val() ? 'red' : 'green');

});
```

Comment: same thing is happening code is working from console not when i add in the header template. I have inserted the code, you can check in view source

Comment: No chance, code is correct but still its not working on my site, dont know why

Answer (score -1):

Card number field is working correct because of this code

```
    jQuery('#stripe-card-number').on('keyup', function ($) {
    if (jQuery(this).val().length > 0) {
        jQuery('#stripe-card-number').css('border', '2px solid #69bf29');
            }
    });
```

So, similaraly you need to trigger your code on keyup event for expiration date and cvv

```
jQuery('.wc-credit-card-form-card-expiry').on('keyup', function ($) {

   if (jQuery('.input-text.wc-credit-card-form-card-expiry').val() == '') {
       jQuery('.input-text.wc-credit-card-form-card-expiry').css('border-color', 'red');
   }
   else {
       jQuery('.input-text.wc-credit-card-form-card-expiry').css('border-color', 'green');
   }

});
```

Comment: No Even the on event is not workin. I mean when i write on console it works. currently card number is working through css but there is no class for expiration date and cvv. may be I am assuming jQuery is not working on this section because this section is loading separately. If you see there is loader on this section

Comment: but, In your website, i didn't find any event for card expiry field

Comment: I added, you can check now